# Angular 10, generating component class dynamically causes compilation error

Tags: angular, function, components, factory, dynamically-generated

I am looking for a way to **generate component classes in runtime**, dynamically and use them in NgModule's but always getting a compilation error `Value could not be determined statically.`.
I've tried to isolate the problem and could not make compiler accept even the simplest example

```js
export function generate() {
  class Test {
    title = 'example';
  }

  Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    template: '<span>{{title}}</span>',
  })(Test);

  return Test;
}
```

`generate()` function then simply called in NgModule declaration.

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent, generate } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    generate()
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
✔ Compiled successfully.

    Error: src/app/app.module.ts:8:17 - error NG1010: Value at position 1 in the NgModule.declarations of AppModule is not a reference
      Value could not be determined statically.

     8   declarations: [
                       ~
     9     AppComponent,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    10     generate()
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    11   ],
       ~~~

      src/app/app.module.ts:10:5
        10     generate()
               ~~~~~~~~~~
        Unable to evaluate function call of complex function. A function must have exactly one return statement.
      src/app/app.component.ts:12:1
         12 export function generate() {
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         13   class Test {
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        ...
         22   return Test;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         23 }
            ~
        Function is declared here.
```

The question is, is there a way to make it work? What am I missing or how to fix an example above to make dynamically generated class be accepted as a component class?

EDIT: I could not find a solution for AOT compilation, so my best bet is using JIT prod build which includes compiler in runtime.

```json
    "start": "ng serve --no-aot",
    "build": "ng build --prod --no-aot",
```

Answer (score 0):

> Angular Schematics

*`cyrilletuzi.angular-schematics`*

Have you tried using this vs code extension?

Comment: Hi, could you please explain, how is this related to error in compiling Angular app?

Comment: If u generate component with this extension, you never get errors during compilation.

Comment: The question is not in generating component using CLI but generating component class in runtime